# At what levels do the various types of weapons start to appear in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd like to know at what various levels do the various types of weapons appear in Skyrim for example Elven, and Daedric. I've looked at various things on Google that relate to this but nothing I've looked at has the answer so if anyone knows the answer to this question, please let me know thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Weapons article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weapons) at UESP, these are the minimum player levels for finding weapons of specific materials:

1: Iron
2: Steel
6: Orcish
12: Dwarven
18: Nordic
19: Elven
27: Glass
35: Stalhrim
36: Ebony
46: Daedric

Weapons of other materials are not found randomly in the wild.

From the article on [dungeons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dungeons), some dungeons have a minimum level. If you enter a level-12 dungeon but your character is a lower level than that, you (apparently) may find any weapon material up to Dwarven. I haven't tested this myself.